# Why does venv command give me parse error?

Tags: python, command, zsh

I am trying to follow the instructions of this codebase: https://github.com/obaghirli/syn10-diffusion

I used `python3 -m venv venv`
instead of `python3.8 -m venv venv` as I do not have python3.8

I am getting an error in this command: `(venv) python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` that says
zsh: parse error near `python`

I tried the same command with python3 also, but getting the same error. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: `(venv)` should not be part of the command.

Comment: Since zsh is complaining, this is not related to Python. The command is obviously wrong. Since you found the command already, you can fix it with a text editor. I just wonder at which point you are running a zsh script. What is your `python3` exactly? (i.e. do a `type python3` to find out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `(venv) python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` as a command you should do

```bash
. ./venv/bin/activate
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The instructions you are following are poorly written.

Typically, instructions that involve running commands at a command line are presented with a `$` representing the prompt, which helps distinguish between the commands you enter and the expected output of those commands. Step 1 would thus be written

```
$ git clone ...
$ cd syn10-diffusion
```

These instructions don't do that, which is fine. (People often *do* confuse the `$` with part of the command to type.

Step 2, however, omits the `$` marker while *including* the string `(venv)` which is something `venv/bin/activate` will add to the prompt to indicate that the virtual environment named `venv` is, in fact, activate. Step 2 might more clearly be written

```
$ python3.8 -m venv env
$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ python -m pip install -r requirements
```

Only the text *after* the `$` is intended to be typed; everything before and up to the `$` is intended to represent the prompt, whatever *your* prompt might look like.